# How to implement UnitTesting for ServiceBusTrigger (QUEUE,TOPIC)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, mstest

**I need to write Test for this Azure function**

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
public async Task Run( [ServiceBusTrigger("QueueName", 
   Connection = "Connectionstring")]string myQueueItem ){
   await _Service.ProcessMessage(myQueueItem);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test? If `_Service.ProcessMessage()` is called?

Comment: you should unit test _Service only